# Custom filters produces infinit digest loop with angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-filters, angular-meteor

I have the problem, that custom filters are producing an infinit digest loop in angular-meteor. ([Angular error description page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:30,%22oldVal%22:26%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item1%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item2%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item3%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item4%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:34,%22oldVal%22:30%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item1%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item2%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item3%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item4%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:38,%22oldVal%22:34%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item1%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item2%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item3%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item4%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:42,%22oldVal%22:38%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item1%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item2%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item3%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item4%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:46,%22oldVal%22:42%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item1%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item2%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item3%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%22item4%22%7D%5D%5D))

I made a working example in this [plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/BvJlFU54itbO98QU91ZN/) with pure angular. When I try the same with angular-meteor in es6 style, the script is running in the infinit loop.

This is my controller

```
class MyController {
  constructor($scope, $reactive) {
    'ngInject';
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    this.items = [{ item: 'item1' }, { item: 'item2' }, { item: 'item3' }, { item: 'item4' }];    
  }
}
```

And this is the template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items | testFilter">
  Item: {{item.item}}
</div>
```

The filter implementation just makes a copy of the original content (so it filters nothing but it's ok for demonstration).

```
[...]
.filter('testFilter', () => {
  return (items) => {
    var result = angular.copy(items);
    // maybe splice some elements from result
    return result;
  };
})
[...]
```

I don't understand the reason why this is working in plain angularjs but not working in meteor. Is it because of the es6=>es5 translation? Am I missing something and using filters the wrong way? Or did I find an angular-meteor bug?

I'd be glad for some advice. :)

### Update

- I figured out, that only the last filter in a chain produces this error. So it might happen, when the variable is passed to the scope.
- The ES6=>ES5 translation seems to be fine for me, when I check the result in the build directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a generic workaround for this problem, so when migrating an existing angular application to meteor, the logic of custom filters can stay untouched in many cases. ([Gist with comments](https://gist.github.com/davemecha/0e01c2e32f9077b062246916173a5897))

```
    .filter('fixLoopFilter', () => {
        const instanceCache = {};

        return (items) => {
            const hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(angular.toJson(items)).toString();
            if (!instanceCache[hash]) instanceCache[hash] = [];
            instanceCache[hash].length = 0;
            items.map((item) => {
                instanceCache[hash].push(item);
            });
            return instanceCache[hash];
        };
    })
```

It doesn't really filter any element of the input array but returns a clone of the input. The clone is the same instance for each input configuration. It's not a deep clone. If the input array contains objects, the result array will contain the same instances.

Usage:

1. Add this filter to the base module of your project.
2. Use it in your template as the **last** filter applied in a chain:

   ```
   ng-repeat="vm.items | customFilter | fixLoopFilter"
   ```

Drawbacks:

This filter can be performance and memory consuming for a large input array or a large Array of objets. It is just meant as a workarount till the issue is fixed or there is a better workaround for this issue.